# I cant get $result['query'] in my view page

Tags: codeigniter

My controller Erp_c:

```
$result['query2']= $this->erp_m->selectattend1($user,$en,$year,$month);
$this->load->('salview',$result);
```

In model Erp_m:

```
function selectattend1($user,$en,$year,$month)
{
  $query2=$this->db->query(" SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM attendance3
WHERE name = '$en'
AND attend = 'Absent'
AND MONTH = '$month'
AND year = '$year'
AND user = '$user' ");

return $query2->result(); 

}
```

In view page salview.php:

```
 foreach($query2 as $row)

{
$al=$row->count(*);///here what i put ,that is my doubt
,because $result['query']= Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [COUNT(*)] => 1 ) )
}
```

How can I get count value in view page?

Comment: why you counting in view??

Answer (score 0):

In Controller

```
$result['query2']= $this->erp_m->selectattend1($user,$en,$year,$month);//get data
$result['count']= $this->erp_m->get_selectattend1_count($user,$en,$year,$month);//get count
```

In Model

```
function selectattend1($user,$en,$year,$month)
{
    $query2 = $this->db->query(" SELECT COUNT(*)
            FROM attendance3
            WHERE name = '$en'
            AND attend = 'Absent'
            AND MONTH = '$month'
            AND year = '$year'
            AND user = '$user' ");

    $result = $query2->result_array();
    return $result;
}

function get_selectattend1_count($user,$en,$year,$month)
{
    $query2 = $this->db->query(" SELECT COUNT(*)
            FROM attendance3
            WHERE name = '$en'
            AND attend = 'Absent'
            AND MONTH = '$month'
            AND year = '$year'
            AND user = '$user' ");

    $result = $query2->result_array();
    $count = count($result);
    return $count;
}
```

In View

you can access both veriables `$query2` and `$count`

```
foreach($query2 as $row)
{
    echo $row['field_name'];
}
```

Comment: how i access $count in view page, i did this in view page

Comment: you can use `foreach{}` loop or just use `echo print_r($count);`

Comment: if one more count is there for eg:$result['count1']= $this->erp_m->get_selectattend2_count($user,$en,$year,$month); eg:in model erp_m $query3 = $this->db->query(" SELECT COUNT(*)
            FROM attendance3
            WHERE name = '$en'
            AND attend = 'present'
            AND MONTH = '$month'
            AND year = '$year'
            AND user = '$user' ");$result = $query3->result_array();
//print_r($result);die;
        $count1 = count($result);
        return $count1; ,but i cant get $count1 in view page

Comment: what you want do actually with the count??

Comment: i want to take no of  leaves the person had taken                                         (no of present and no of leaves)

Comment: i cant get your purpose still

Comment: from $result['count'] i will get the absent days and $result['count1'] i will get no of present days , i will get $count and $count1 in view page,but i am getting answer 1 for both