# I cant fetch as array

Tags: php, codeigniter

```
$sql=SELECT COUNT( * ) FROM attendance3 WHERE name = 'Hema' AND attend = 'Absent' AND MONTH = 'July' AND year = '2015' AND user = 'mars'.
```

In php we can get the count

```
$res=mysql_query($sql);
$row=mysql_fetch_array($res);    
$count=$row['COUNT(*)'];////say 4;
```

How will we get this in codeigniter?

```
controller Erp_c
$result['count']= $this->erp_m->selectattend1($user,$en,$year,$month);
```

model erp_m

```
function selectattend1($user,$en,$year,$month)
{
  $query2=$this->db->query(" SELECT COUNT(*)
  FROM attendance3
  WHERE name = '$en'
  AND attend = 'Absent'
  AND MONTH = '$month'
  AND year = '$year'
  AND user = '$user' ");

//return $query2->result(); 
  $result = $query2->result_array();
        $count = count($result);
        return $count;  
  }
```

In view page how will we get $count//how many times $row is repeating that is I want..

I did this

```
foreach($query2 as $row)
{

$count=$row->COUNT(*);////SHOWING ERROR;
}
```

I want how many days the student is present or absent

Comment: Try changing `SELECT COUNT(*)` to `SELECT COUNT(*) attendance_count` and then using `$row->attendance_count` to get the value.

Comment: Same question you ask 2 hr before http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31400526/i-cant-get-resultquery-in-my-view-page

Answer (score 1):

you need to change model function.

```
function selectattend1($user,$en,$year,$month)
 {
       $where=array('name'=>$en,'attend'=>'Absent','MONTH'=>$month,'year'=>$year,'user'=>$user);
$this->db->where($where);
$res=$this->db->get('attendance3');
$num=$res->num_rows();
 return $num;


}
```

it will return number of record found and it will be assigned to
       `$result['count']= $this->erp_m->selectattend1($user,$en,$year,$month);`in controller. now you need to load this $result variable in loading of view like 
     `$this->load->view('filename',$result);`

now you can use `$count` variable directly in view.